# How to decode a JSON key that could contain a json array OR single json object in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I need to decode a JSON file with a key that sometimes contain a single JSON object and sometimes an array of JSON objects. How do I decode it properly without getting typeMismatch error?

If it contains a single JSON object, I'd like to decode it into an array of one object.

Here is how I implemented my decoder (The key in question is .prediction, and I'm decoding it as Prediction object/array):

```
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)

if let prediction = try container.decode([Prediction]?.self, forKey: .prediction) {
            self.prediction = prediction
        } else if let prediction = try container.decode(Prediction?.self, forKey: .prediction) {
            self.prediction = [prediction]
        } else {self.prediction = []}
```

Comment: Use `try?` instead of `try`? Ie ignore the error that should be a mismatch error, or catch them each time and fallback...

Comment: A bit unrelated but the question mark in `Prediction?.self` makes no sense.

Comment: What is `self.prediction` as you seem to be treating the same property as having multiple types, both `Prediction` and `[Prediction]`

Comment: It works using `try?`. Thank you! I don't know how to upvote